# In jQuery, using ajaxSend to preview the url built by $.post call

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I construct my ajaxSend call, this seems like the place to put it, to preview what is being passed back to the broker? also, can I stop the ajax call in ajaxSend?..so I can perfect my url string before dealing with errors from the broker?

This is the complete URL that, when passed to the broker, will return the JSON code I need:

```
http://myServer/cgi-bin/broker?service=myService&program=myProgram&section=mySection&start=09/08/08&end=09/26/08
```

This is my $.post call (not sure it is creating the above url string)

```
$(function() {
 $("#submit").bind("click",
  function() {
   $.post({
     url: "http://csewebprod/cgi-bin/broker" ,
     datatype: "json",
     data: {
      'service' : myService,
      'program' : myProgram,
      'section' : mySection,
      'start' : '09/08/08',
      'end' : '09/26/08'
      },
     error: function(request){
      $("#updateHTML").removeClass("hide") ;
      $("#updateHTML").html(request.statusText);
      },
     success: function(request) {
      $("#updateHTML").removeClass("hide") ;
      $("#updateHTML").html(request) ;
      }
    }); // End post method
   }); // End bind method
  }); // End eventlistener
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to preview the HTTP request being sent is to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox. Download and enable the plugin, and when the request is made it will show up in the firebug console.

Comment: thanks, firebug helped me make sure I was sending a proper url to the server

Answer (score 1):

[API/1.2/Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxSend#callback) has information on how to bind to AJAX events.

```
// Hook into jQuery's ajaxSend event, which is triggered before every ajax
// request.
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
  // settings.data is either a query string like "id=1&x=foo" or null

  // It can be modified like this (assuming AUTH_TOKEN is defined eslewhere)
  settings.data =
    ((settings.data) ? settings.data + "&" : "") +
    "authenticity_token=" + encodeURIComponent(AUTH_TOKEN);
});
```