# jQuery $.ajaxSend() settings.data is null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I found strange bug (maybe). When I send parameters to $.ajax in a form of hash, and tried to check that params in $.ajaxSend, I found that settings.data is null, settings.url was normal with parameters included. Then I look inside jQuery code, and found that data erased.

```
    // If data is available, append data to url for get requests
    if ( s.data && type == "GET" ) {
        s.url += (s.url.match(/\?/) ? "&" : "?") + s.data;

        // IE likes to send both get and post data, prevent this
        s.data = null;
    }
```

Now I am in need of parsing url ((. What to do?

[In JQuery, using ajaxSend to preview the url built by $.post call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885/in-jquery-using-ajaxsend-to-preview-the-url-built-by-post-call)

Here in comments I see that data should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default anything passed as data that is not a String is processed and transformed into a query string. So, if you use POST to skip the bug:

```
 $.post({
      url: "http://yourserver/ajax" ,
      data: {param1: 'val1', param2:'val2'}
 });
```

in `$.ajaxSend` the value of `settings.data` will be `'param1=val1&param2=val2'` and you will need to parse the parameters, like with GET.

If you want to avoid parsing the url or data just add a copy of the data when building the settings object. The extra parameter should not cause any problem.

```
 var data = {param1: 'val1', param2:'val2'};
 $.get({
      url: "http://yourserver/ajax" ,
      data: data,
      dataCopy: data
 });
```

Then, in `$.ajaxSend` you can check the values in `settings.dataCopy`.